# Can I use Secure Folder without a Samsung Account?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-a3

On a Samsung Galaxy A3 2017 (A-320FL) I want to use the Secure Folder feature. Clicking on the Icon opens a prompt to sign in to a Samsung Account.

I don't want sync anything (or create another account with all of its privacy implications), just want to have password protected clones of apps and storage.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to use Samsung's Secure Folder without logging in to Samsung. I don't know why Samsung requires that you log in to a Samsung account to use Secure Folder, as that seems to increase the potential attack surface.

Comment: The answer is simple: Lust for user data. Security is secondary to this.